# Taking mean of all students for one subject using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL table of students with one subject. I would like to take the mean of all the students for this particular subject such that:

`Sum of the subject/Number of total students`

The table looks like this:

```
Student ID : 1
=============
Maths : 40

Student ID : 2
=============
Maths : 60

Student ID : 3
=============
Maths : 90

Student ID : 4
=============
Maths : 0
```

So if the student has scored 0, then ignore this student and its score in calculating the mean.

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db;charset=utf8",'user','');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Students";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);

while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
 //How to take the mean of 1 subject for all students?
}
?>
```

Comment: Just so you know *student has scored 0, then ignore* That wouldn't work to calculate mean you still include them otherwise the number will be higher with lesser students who passed.If 1 student gets 99 and the remaining 9 get 0 and you*ignore* them... then your mean will be 99% and that's wrong

Comment: @KevinGales exactly. But the 0 is also if the student has not attended the exam. So such case I do not want to include the student in the mean. For example in the above the number of students in the mean will be only 3.

Comment: How about if the student attended but got zero?Are they considered absent too?

Comment: The thing is, we will be adding "null" if the student is absent or did not attend.

Comment: Okay I get it now

Answer (score 0):

Fix this line first so that...you can only get scores greater that 0

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE subjectscore > 0"; //assuming your column for scores is "subjectscore"
```

The the rest of the code to get mean should be

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql);

while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                 $sumparts .= $data->subjectscore."+"; //Add a delimiter after every returned obj

                                           }

print_r($sumparts); //For debug :to see which ones are selected

$sumarr = explode("+",$sumparts); // Convert the delimited string to array
    $sum = array_sum($sumarr); //Get sum of values of array in this case the scores
    $divisor = count($sumarr) - 1; //The minus 1 is necessary since well the delimited string will always have 1 extra key therefore making the count to count 1 more unnnecessary key 

$total = $sum/$divisor; //Sum of all divided by the total number of objects

echo $total;
```